# IAM Policy to limit SageMaker resource creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating an AWS IAM policy for SageMaker.

My requirement is to create an IAM policy that limits user's permissions to create only 5 endpoints.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your own APIs, which invoke SageMaker APIs at the back, to introduced the said permission mechanics without heavily relying on an IAM policy.

---

Because an IAM policy does not have an aggregation capability like counting the number of resources, it might be quite difficult or impossible to realize the said permission using just an IAM policy.

Using tag-based conditions and enforcing an user-identity-basis resource ARN pattern on resource creation might help, but it means your application has to do some works to introduce these permission logics. Thus, I suggest creating your own APIs anyway.